# The base class includes the field 'btnLogin', but its type (FoodOrder.App_Code.LinkButtonDefault) is not compatible

Tags: c#, asp.net

> The base class includes the field
>   'btnLogin', but its type
>   (FoodOrder.App_Code.LinkButtonDefault)
>   is not compatible with the type of
>   control
>   (FoodOrder.App_Code.LinkButtonDefault).

aspx:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="FoodOrder.App_Code" TagPrefix="ac1" %>
<ac1:LinkButtonDefault ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Prijava" CssClass="gumbek" 
                onclick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

LinkButtonDefault:

```
namespace FoodOrder.App_Code
{
    public class LinkButtonDefault : LinkButton
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "addClickFunctionScript",
                _addClickFunctionScript, true);

            string script = String.Format(_addClickScript, ClientID);
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "click_" + ClientID,
                script, true);
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        private const string _addClickScript = "addClickFunction('{0}');";

        private const string _addClickFunctionScript =
            @"  function addClickFunction(id) {{
            var b = document.getElementById(id);
            if (b && typeof(b.click) == 'undefined') b.click = function() {{
                var result = true; if (b.onclick) result = b.onclick();
                if (typeof(result) == 'undefined' || result) {{ eval(b.getAttribute('href')); }}
            }}}};";
    }
}
```

aspx.designer.cs:

```
protected global::FoodOrder.App_Code.LinkButtonDefault btnLogin;
```

Can someone explain me error?

Comment: (Hijacking this for a private message) @senzacionale: It's not very good etiquette to delete questions after viable answers have already been given...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a circular reference occuring with the App_Code folder.

MS recommends two approaches to fix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919284

Either modify the web.config to set the `<compilation>` element to false (only recommended for small applications)

OR

Reorder the folders in your application.  AKA - put your link button class somewhere else.

Comment: Just hit this problem and lead me to the fix, my control is structured as follows
/abc/control2.ascx -> references control1.ascx
/def/control1.ascx

Now if I compile and run aspnet merge, everything is fine. But instead of single web.dll, I get an extra dll for control1. Fix was simply move control2 into control1's folder (/def)

Comment: My problem (quite some years later!) seems to have been this, although not inside the App_Code folder, but between aspx and ascx files in various folders. It was particularly gnarly because the error was not reported about code I had just changed -- it seems I already had the somewhat unnatural dependency from folder UserControls/Y to folder X, and I added a new dependency from X to UserControls/Y. The compiler tried to work around it by making extra DLLs but I got the error on deployment. A shame the KB articles have been deleted, but it is archived at https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/919284