# The base class includes the field 'OpenAuthLogin', but its type (OpenAuthProviders) is not compatible with the type of control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webforms app in VS2013/C# using Owin Authentication generated with vs2013 wizard and copied all the authentication code into my older webforms project which is using .NET 4.5 but had openid authentication and now I changed to openauth2.

When I try to access the login.aspx page I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to
service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details
and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field 'OpenAuthLogin',
but its type (OpenAuthProviders) is not compatible with the type of control 
(ASP.account_openauthproviders_ascx).
```

this is the line where the error occurs:

```
Line 18:      <section id="socialLoginForm">
Line 19:         <h2>Use a service to log in.</h2>
Line 20:         <uc:OpenAuthProviders runat="server" ID="OpenAuthLogin" />
Line 21:      </section>

Source File: /Account/Login.aspx    Line: 20
```

This is the **web.config** file with connection strings removed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>    
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- removed for privacy -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrators" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="12288" executionTimeout="160" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,*,:,\,?" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Errors/GenericError.aspx">
      <!-- <error statusCode="403" redirect="ErrorPages/Error403_NoAccess.aspx"/> -->
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="Errors/Error500.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Errors/Error404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <pages pageParserFilterType="Omari.Web.UI.WhiteSpaceCleaner, WhiteSpaceCleanerForWebFormsAndMVC2">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>      
      <controls>

        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" /></controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory,           System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,           PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add verb="*" path="facebookouth.axd" type="VineMedia.Facebook.FacebookOAuthHandler, VineMedia.Facebook" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" />
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Telerik.Skin" value="MetroTouch" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/Error404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="RadUploadModule" />
      <remove name="RadCompression" />
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
      <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
      <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="FaceBookOAuth" path="facebookouth.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="VineMedia.Facebook.FacebookOAuthHandler, VineMedia.Facebook" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="12582912" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security> 
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Facebook" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.10.0" newVersion="6.0.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>      
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>      
    </assemblyBinding>

    <!-- This prevents the Windows Event Log from frequently logging that HMAC1 is being used (when the other party needs it). -->
    <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />    
  </runtime>
  <system.net>    
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />

  </system.net>

  <uri>
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

This the **login.aspx** file

```
<%@ Page Title="Log in" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Account_Login" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Account/OpenAuthProviders.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="OpenAuthProviders" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div class="inner-container half group">
        <div class="box-hold group">
            <article class="post-6 page type-page status-publish hentry entry box" id="post-6">
                <div class="entry-intro">
                    <hgroup class="title">
                        <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
                    </hgroup>
                </div><!-- .entry-intro -->

                <div class="entry-content group">

                    <div style="text-align: center;">

                        <section id="socialLoginForm">
                            <h2>Use a service to log in.</h2>
                            <uc:OpenAuthProviders runat="server" ID="OpenAuthLogin" />
                        </section>

                        <%--<section id="loginForm" style="text-align: center;">--%>
                        <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>

                        <div class="loginform1">
                            <div class="title">
                                <img src="/content/themes/pin/images/login-logo.png" width="280" height="42" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="body">
                                <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
                                </p>
                                <fieldset>

                                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="log-lab" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="login-input-user" ID="UserName" Font-Size="15px" />
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />

                                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="log-lab">Password</asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="login-input-pass" Font-Size="15px" />
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />

                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" />
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="checkbox">Remember me?</asp:Label>

                                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log in" CssClass="button" />
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <p>
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="RegisterHyperLink" ViewStateMode="Disabled" Font-Bold="True">Register</asp:HyperLink> if you don't have an account.
                        </p>

                    <%--</section>--%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the **OpenAuthProviders.aspx** file

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="OpenAuthProviders.ascx.cs" Inherits="OpenAuthProviders" %>

<div id="socialLoginList">
    <h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>
    <hr />
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="providerDetails" ItemType="System.String"
        SelectMethod="GetProviderNames" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" value="<%#: Item %>"
                    title="Log in using your <%#: Item %> account.">
                    <%#: Item %>
                </button>
            </p>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div>
                <p>There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252803">this article</a> for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.</p>
            </div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

Comment: What us your web.config ? This error can occur when moving between .net runtimes. Did you copy files from newer ASP.NET version to older ?

Comment: no, the .NET version is the same, 4.5. I will add the web.config, but it's large.

Comment: I have added the web.config file

Comment: could be some conflict between user control field name and class field name, aren't they the same? You can also try to specify assembly name like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230599/base-class-includes-field-but-type-not-compatible-with-type-of-control

Comment: If I specify the assembly, then I get this error: Parser Error Message: The 'assembly' attribute is not supported on this directive when a 'tagname' attribute is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that the generated website from which I copied to authentication code was a Web Project and the other one was Web Application and needs different code.